# Programatically added checkbox to ContextMenu: Text gets chopped. Strange

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to add a set of submenus to a contextmenu programatically. In this context I ran into a problem. For example one takes the following minimal example:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (PropagationFlags entry in PropagationFlags.GetValues(typeof(PropagationFlags)))
            {
                RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
                rb.Text = entry.ToString();

                rb.Tag = entry;
                rb.AutoSize = true;

                ToolStripControlHost Ch = new ToolStripControlHost(rb);
                Ch.AutoSize = true;

                ((ToolStripMenuItem)contextMenuStrip.Items["testEntry"]).DropDown.Items.Add(Ch);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

The Contextmenu here gets three subitems (which is correct) but unfortunately the text of the last item gets chopped (should be InheritOnly). (see screenshot 1). [image: screenshot1]

When I now modify the code and add an additional item like this:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (PropagationFlags entry in PropagationFlags.GetValues(typeof(PropagationFlags)))
            {
                RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
                rb.Text = entry.ToString();

                rb.Tag = entry;
                rb.AutoSize = true;

                ToolStripControlHost Ch = new ToolStripControlHost(rb);
                Ch.AutoSize = true;

                ((ToolStripMenuItem)contextMenuStrip.Items["testEntry"]).DropDown.Items.Add(Ch);

            }

            RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton();
            rb2.Text = "test";
            rb2.AutoSize = true;

            ToolStripControlHost Ch2 = new ToolStripControlHost(rb2);
            Ch2.AutoSize = true;

            ((ToolStripMenuItem)contextMenuStrip.Items["testEntry"]).DropDown.Items.Add(Ch2);
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine and also subitem numnber three gets it complete text. See the following screenshot [image]

This happens with various enums, not only with this one.

Is anybody here aware of this behavior or able to reproduce it? I'm using VS 2013 Professional.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution or at least a workaround. It really helps to add another item programatically and remove it again directly. I have no clue why this works and still consider this being a bug of C# but at least I found a workaround......

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is seen at specific text lengths, and can be reproduced much simpler than your example above.  Just use "PropogationFlags.None".

[image]

The core cause is due to the wrong `Font` used when the `RadioButton` is first initialized. When subsequent items are added, the `Font` is set properly and corrects itself.

To fix your code above, explicitly set the `Font` of either the `RadioButton` or the `ToolStripControlHost` to match the host `ToolStripItem`.

```
private static void AddItem(ToolStripDropDownItem menuItem, object item)
{
    var button = new RadioButton {Text = item.ToString()};
    var host = new ToolStripControlHost(button)
        {
            Font = menuItem.Font
        };

    menuItem.DropDown.Items.Add( host );
}
```

[image]